# Why PHP include file contents getting displayed

Tags: php, class, include

I have two php files feed.php and main.php.

In main.php, I am using feed.php.

### feed.php

```
class RSSFeed {

    var $channel_url;
    var $channel_title;
    var $channel_description;
    var $channel_lang;
};
```

### main.php

```
<html>
<body>

<?php include 'feed.php'; ?>
<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

when I run main.php, I got the following output

```
class RSSFeed {

    var $channel_url;
    var $channel_title;
    var $channel_description;
    var $channel_lang;

}
```

Welcome to my home page!

> Some text.

I am not able to understand why I see the contents of RSSFeed class when I display the main.php in browser?

Comment: http://php.net/include - one of the first things to learn about includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you forgot to put `<?php` and `?>` on feed.php. That file is treated like plain text and is displayed in the HTML.

```
<?php
class RSSFeed {

    var $channel_url;
    var $channel_title;
    var $channel_description;
    var $channel_lang;
};
?>
```

Comment: `?>` is optional and is recommended to be omitted from the end of a file so as not to accidentally include trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to put

```
<?php
```

In the first line of your feed.php

Answer (score 1):

May be you forgot the `<?php` at start and `?>` at end of your `feed.php`

```
<?php
class RSSFeed {

    var $channel_url;
    var $channel_title;
    var $channel_description;
    var $channel_lang;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted the exact text that is in feed.php, then you are missing the `<?php` and `?>` tags that need to go around it. Otherwise, the PHP doesn't know it needs to process it, and thinks it's just a plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine assuming you have

```
<html>
<body>

<?php include 'main.php'; ?>
<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<?php
class RSSFeed {

    var $channel_url;
    var $channel_title;
    var $channel_description;
    var $channel_lang;

}
?>
```

In the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

More then likely, you forgot to wrap the class page "feed.php" in  tags.

Also, since what you are reading in is a class, I would recommend doing:

```
<?php require_once('feed.php'); ?>
```

This will keep you from loading the same file in multiple times.

Trust me, it will save you a headache later.